# VB.Net editor removes one line of code every time debug is started

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-community

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and my problem is - every time when I click debug, one line of code is moved to the right of the previous line from the current file being edited. Some of my coworkers have seen this behavior too. C# works fine. It happens only in VB.NET with all file types: web.config, .vb, .aspx. This causes a problem because the line is removed after the project is compiled, so the debugger can never hit breakpoint because it says that the source code is different from the original that was before compilation.

Before Debug Click

[image: Before Debug Click]

After Debug Click

[image: After Debug Click]

Comment: Wouldn't it be code optimisation that is enabled? Like a declaration of a variable that is never used (for debugging) and the optimizer get ride of it? I've never seen it in c# but I know some of these lines are not reached while debugging when the code optimization is on.

Comment: Can you share that line of code? Do you use any code cleanup,formatting utilities with auto format/cleanup on save or something?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, Mathew, Is not one line specificlly, the line with the editing cursor is the one that gets removed, I'm using Resharper's lastest version.

Comment: Thanks Piou I'm going to check code optimization and let you know.

Comment: This should be a good thing. If you hienout debug enough times, there won't be any code left, and debugging will be very easy. :-) Seriously, how would you expect anyone to help if you can't provide something that would allow us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your comment, and you're kind of right I'm editing the question, the line is not really removed it is wrapped to the right of the previous line, and this behavior is difficult to reproduce and to explain too because it is not code crashing related, it happens after compilation, thanks for the downvote I guess, it will help me to write better questions next time.

Comment: I uploaded screenshoots.

Comment: @DavidRobles that is strange. Does the line of code go back to it's original place after you finish debugging or does it stay wrapped? I've never seen this kind of behaviour so I agree we will find it hard to replicate. Would be interesting to know what is causing it.

Comment: Does it happen if you use F5 as well?

Comment: @Jinx88909 thanks for your help, it doesn't go back when debugging finish, I'm trying to believe it's a Resharper because it has a feature called Line Wrapping but I've modified everithig and the behavior continues.

Comment: That could be it though. Removing it would give you a better idea and/or repairing VS? I don't use Resharper so unsure if this kind of behaviour would happen and what the config side of it is like.

Comment: @topshot thanks for your help, I tried with F5 and it continues moving the line.

Comment: you could start VS on safemode, that will disable all plugins and 3rd party addons

Comment: @ David Robles, I agree with Jaxedin's suggestion, we'd better to make sure that it is not related to the add-ins/extension tools firstly. If possible, you could run your VS in safe mode, or just disable/remove the extension tools/add-ins like the resharper or others, and then re-debug it again. Or you have other clean VS IDE which has no the extension tools, test it again. At least, we could know that whether it is related to your VS IDE or the project itself.

Comment: @Jaxedin, I tried with safe mode and indeed it works fine, so maybe it is a Resharper's thing.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I tried with safe mode and indeed it works fine, so maybe it is a Resharper's thing.

Comment: @David Robles, glad to know that we find the reason, I add the comment as the answer:) You can mark it if it is helpful for you. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue looks quite similar to one described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-402877), so try a workaround:

> In my case, the linke break problem only happens if you have
>   DevExpress components AND the Licences.licx file exists in you
>   project. Emptying the licences.licx file in a pre-build event fixes
>   the problem and resharper no longer removes a line break.

Comment: Thanls for your help Alexander, indeed it was a devexpress patch causing trouble with the licenses.licx file, I added the pre-build event and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

If it works well in safe mode, it would be related to the extension tools/add-ins in your VS, as you said that you installed certain extension tools like Resharper or others, you could disable/remove them one by one under TOOLS->Extensions and Updates, so it could help us narrow down this issue:)