# Something is moving focused code line to top row when the project starts

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

In my Visual Studio 2017 project, something is moving focused code line to top row when the project starts. It seemed to me that ReSharper was doing it, but I could not find it 2 days.

**EDIT:** In the following gif image, when you run the project, the closed bracket under the cursor is flowing to the top line, near of the cursor. If there was a code snippet on the bottom line, it would flow this time.

**Edit after some good comments:** The problem is caused from ReSharper. Because the problem is solved when I disable ReSharper by following `Tools -> Extensions and Updates... -> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2018.1.3 -> Disable`. Emptying or deleting the `licences.licx` file did not solve the problem.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.Net editor removes one line of code every time debug is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627447/vb-net-editor-removes-one-line-of-code-every-time-debug-is-started)

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627447/vb-net-editor-removes-one-line-of-code-every-time-debug-is-started/41714255#41714255